# WHERE condition with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm deleting table content that matches username in all four tables..ie..if i delete one record of username 'user1' from 1st table..it should delete the record in all the tables where username is 'AAA'.

the tables i use is

```
table 1 : p_user_profile

p_id        username  
----        --------
1           AAA
```

table 2 : p_device_id

```
d_id        username 
----        --------
1           AAA
```

table 3 : p_temp_notification

```
p_id        username   type
----        --------   -----
1           AAA          i
```

table 4 : p_sent_notification

```
p_id        username   type
----        --------   -----
1           AAA          i
```

here i want to delete the records that matches the username from all tables and match with of type="i" from 3 & 4 tables.

below is the code i used :

```
$p_id = intval($_REQUEST['p_id']);
include 'db/connection.php';
$sql= "DELETE p_user_profile, p_device_id, p_sent_notification FROM p_user_profile LEFT JOIN p_device_id ON p_device_id.username = p_user_profile.username
                                                                                   LEFT JOIN p_sent_notification ON p_device_id.username = p_sent_notification.username WHERE p_id = $p_id AND p_sent_notification.type = "i" ";
```

In the ablove query, if i execute with one WHERE condition it is successfully executing..but it is deleting type of all records..but i want to delete records of only type="i"..

Plz help in resolving..Thankyou

Comment: `intval` is not a substitute for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: try changing your query to use single quotes, like this: `p_sent_notification.type = 'i'`

Comment: @tadman For numbers it is enough... string will be converted to 0. Sometimes is better use intval than _real_escape_string, if you do not use prepared statements.

Comment: Quotes yes and I think it wasn't bad to define which table's p_id you want to use in the where, because you have p_id in 3 tables.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Unless you have a very good reason, prepared statements should be used. It's a lot harder to get them wrong if you're disciplined about doing it right. Relying on tricks like `intval` to escape, turning empty strings into values, is not always a good plan.

Comment: i used single quotes ..but delete option is not working

Comment: can we use WHERE condition with conditions of two tables by using AND. I'm unable to get the output even after changing to p_sent_notification.type = 'i'.

Comment: @tadman it is for integers. And how do you escape `LIMIT $maximum` without intval function?

Comment: @Mr.Smith That's a good reason, but only because PDO urgently needs to add support for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **p_sent_notification** in your query whereas your table name is **sent_notification**

Comment: by mistake i gave table name as sent_notification..it should be p_sent_notification.in query i gave correctly..but it's not working